# Inability to set a NoteProperty to null of a parameter of a method from New-WebServiceProxy

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap, powershell-2.0

Please take a look at the following example

```
$URI = "http://localhost:8080/service.wsdl"
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $URI
$type = $proxy.GetType().Namespace
$request = New-Object($type+".OrderRequest"); 

$request.amount = $null
$request.amount -eq $null # return false
```

amount is of type System.Decimal, I can null other properties but I can't null this particular property and I'm truly baffled.

Here is the definition of the request object as per the wsdl

```
<xs:element xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="OrderReuqest">
<xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:all xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   ...
   <xs:element xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="amount" type="Amount_SimpleType"/>
   ... 
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<simpleType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Amount_SimpleType">
   <restriction xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" base="decimal">
      <fractionDigits xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="6"/>
      <totalDigits xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="18"/>
   </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Here is request object generated from the WSDL by the commandlet

```
PS T:\> New-Object("WebServiceProxy.OrderRequest") | Get-Member | Where-     Object {$_.Name -eq "amount"}


TypeName: WebServiceProxy.OrderRequest

Name   MemberType Definition                      
----   ---------- ----------                      
amount Property   System.Decimal amount {get;set;}
```

So, amount is nullable as per the WSDL but not as per the generated object, can this be changed somehow please?

Answer (score 0):

Most numeric data types are not nullable in .Net.  They will have a default value when they would be assigned a null value.  For example:

```
PS C:\> [decimal]$null
0
PS C:\> [decimal]$null -eq $null
False
```

If you need to have a type be nullable, you need to use the [special nullable datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), specified in Powershell with `[System.Nullable[<datatype>]]` type.

```
PS U:\> [System.Nullable[decimal]]$null
PS U:\> [System.Nullable[decimal]]$null -eq $null
True
```

Many base data types can be declared this way, including all the numeric ones as well as some other datatypes like `[datetime]` or `[timespan]`, but notably there is no `[System.Nullable[string]]`.

However, here you're dealing with a property of an object returned by an arbitrary method.  Unless that property is a nullable datatype in the object's class definition, when you assign `$null` to that value it will get the value `0`.  I don't see a good way for you to get around this without modifying the object definition, which may not be possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bacon-bits, so, the more precise question is now how to configure this for New-WebServiceProxy, I have modified the original question to clarify this, by the way, what's the SO etiquette for this? Should I have created a new question? I'm not sure... it seems arguable either way.. :)

Comment: @lingo_journey I would probably create a new question.  I, for one, don't know the first thing about WSDL or web services, but I gather from Google that you'd need to change it in the service class definition and then re-generate the WSDL in Visual Studio so that the `nillable=true` attribute is in the WSDL.

Comment: Hi @bacon-bits, thanks for your feedback and answers, they have been helpful! nillable=true didn't make a difference; amount being in an "all" element, it should be optional anyhow but New-WebServiceProxy does not allow me to not specify this somehow :(, I'll change a new question for this.